# Some directories on my samba share with identical permissions are not visible

Tags: samba, smb

I have a samba share to a Centos 6 server being mounted on Windows 7. In the shared directory, two or three directories are not visible and can't be navigated to manually either. These directories have the same `drwxr-xr-x` permissions as the others, as well as same user and group. They are not symbolic links. Any suggestion what else could govern visibility to samba?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off SELINUX

Don't know why SELINUX was denying permission to some directories without providing any clear error, but that's what was happening. Disabled SELINUX and all is fine.